# Raspberry Pi 2 Raspbian automatic startup for browser in full screen for Kiosk

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, chromium, raspberry-pi2

I am trying to make my raspberry pi open a set of page's automatically when i start it up in the morning but unfortunately i can't get it to work

i already have the links in chromium so if chromium can start automatically and get to the full screen mode it is solved

so the only thing that needs to happen is to automatically start up chromium 
i tried to use Kiosk for it but it gave me a lot of trouble

this is the code i have right now

```
@chromium-browser --kiosk
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If u want to start your browser in fullscreen mode at boot use the following line in terminal to edit the startup file. (if you're already in root then u dont have to use sudo)

```
sudo nano /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

Then add the following to the startup file.

*For using chromium*

```
@chromium-browser --start-fullscreen
```

It is basically the same as pressing f11 but then automatically.

If u want to add an URL to this u can do that in-between the command and the argument like this.

```
@chromium-browser http://localhost --start-fullscreen
```

This will launch the browser in fullscreen in the requested URL.